# Define custom view in XML class via a sub-class?

Tags: android

I have tried to define my class like this:

```
<view
   class="com.productions.sample.TextCustom"
// more...
/>
```

together with the class:

```
public class TextCustom extends TextView {

    // Stuff.

}
```

However, this works. But what I want to do is this:

```
public final class Custom {

    public class TextCustom extends TextView {

    // Stuff.

    }

    public class ScrollCustom extends ScrollView {

    // Stuff.

    }

}
```

and at the same time be able to define the sub-classes in the XML file, is this possible?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dollar sign as a delimiter:

```
<view class="com.productions.sample.Custom$TextCustom" />
```